# Execute commands on GlassFish inside a application in java

Tags: java, command-line, glassfish, exec, flush

I need to flush a pool in GlassFish when my application detect an specific Error. Is it possible to execute commands on GlassFish inside a java aplication? I just need to flush this pool when a get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with SSH

```
public class FlushPool {

    public static void flushConncetionPool(String nameConnectionPool){
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", port);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword("password");                
            session.connect();

            channel = session.openChannel("shell");


            OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);
            channel.connect();


            ps.println("sudo su -");          
            ps.println("/app/glassfish/glassfish/bin/asadmin --user admin --passwordfile password.txt flush-connection-pool " + nameConnectionPool);
            session.diconect();
            channel.disconect();
        }catch(Exception e){
           // do something
        }


  }
}
```

password.txt must be in server side

```
 AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD = senha
 AS_ADMIN_ADMIN_PASSWORD = senha
 AS_ADMIN_USERPASSWORD=senha 
 AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD= senha
```